# Http header name gets modified

Tags: python, django, http, http-headers

I'm using httplib and django. When I do the following:

```
conn.request("PUT", "/udj/users/3/library/songs", headers={"X-Udj-Ticket-Hash" : hash,
   "content-type" : "text/json"}, body='{"blah": 2}')
```

My server then reports that no header by the name of `X-Udj-Ticket-Hash` was sent. Instead, it shows that a header by the name of `HTTP_X_UDJ_TICKET_HASH` was sent. Why is my header name getting modified? Is django doing this, or is the issue on the client side?

Comment: How are you checking the headers on the server side? Try with a network sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), on either server or client.

Comment: I'm checking the headers on the server side. Wireshark wasn't very helpful as it only gave me raw tcp data.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum: Wireshark also allows you to decode application-level protocols such as HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the issue is with django. From the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/):

> With the exception of CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE, as given above, any HTTP headers in the request are converted to META keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and adding an HTTP_ prefix to the name. So, for example, a header called X-Bender would be mapped to the META key HTTP_X_BENDER.

I really don't like this. Does anyone know why this is done?

Comment: Why do you care? HTTP header field names are case-insensitive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? If I think a value is going to be in a variable named one thing, and it turns out that variable is name something completely different, that's going to completely screw up my program. It's extraordinarily important to me. And it's not just the case that changed. That's easy enough to deal with, you do a case insensitive compare. But then HTTP gets prepended and all the "-" gets turned into "_". That's non-trivial to deal with.

Comment: Kurtis: the case of the header field name does not matter. You will have to deal with that. It seems the server is doing exactly what it's documented to do, and I can't see anything wrong with that...

Comment: Like I said before, it's not just the case that changes. But it's fine, the server documented this behavior and I'll deal. I'm now just curious as to why it does this.